# A request for a particular example in field theory.

Tags: field-theory

I'm looking for an example of the following kind:

Let $a,b\notin \Bbb{Q}$, where $a$ and $b$ satisfy the irreducible polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$ respectively. 
The irreducible polynomial satisfied by $b$ in $\Bbb{Q}(a)[x]$ is not equal to $q(x)$. i.e. it is of a lower degree (preferably of a degree greater than $1$).

Thank you.

Comment: Presumably by "nonzero" you mean "greater than $1$."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan- Yes I did, thanks. I have made the relevant edits.

Answer (score 1):

$a = \sqrt{2}, b = - \sqrt{2}$. For a less silly example, $a = \sqrt[3]{4}, b = \sqrt[3]{2}$.

**Edit:** Try $a = i$ and $b$ a root of $x^2 + (1 + i) x + (1 + i)$. This is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, although I'm not sure how to show that $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ doesn't contain $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ (and it might not be true).

Comment: I would really appreciate a non trivial example. In both the cases that you mention, the inclusion of one term implies the inclusion of the other.

Comment: @Ayush: then you should be more specific. What counts as nontrivial?

Comment: That the inclusion of one term shouldn't necessarily imply the inclusion of the other. Only the degree of the irreducible polynomial that $b$ satisfies in $\Bbb{Q}(a)$ should be less than that which it satisfies in $\Bbb{Q}$. I myself have failed to generate such an example.

Comment: @Ayush: here is a recipe for generating such examples. For simplicity, pick $a$ so that it is an algebraic integer and so that if $K = \mathbb{Q}(a)$ then $\mathcal{O}_K$ has unique factorization. Then use an irreducibility criterion like Eisenstein's criterion to write down a monic irreducible polynomial with coefficients in $\mathcal{O}_K$; let $b$ be one of the roots of this polynomial. Some extra work needs to be done to ensure that $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ doesn't contain $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ (in a fixed algebraic closure, e.g. the algebraic numbers in $\mathbb{C}$); not sure how to do this cleanly.